# Compile python script to ARM v7 32 bit from (OSX | Windows | Ubuntu)

Tags: python, x86, arm, cross-compiling

I have a Seagate D2 NAS running Busybox. The NAS itself runs on a [Marvell Armada 370 ARMv7 32 bit processor](http://dtsheet.com/doc/1285717/armada-370-hardware-specifications) with 512MB of RAM.

I would like to use the same scripts I'm running on all my other servers to keep things as simple as possible.

**How would I go about compiling a standalone python executable for ARMv7 32bit on an x86 platform?**